# Performing JMS stress test with JMeter using pure Java

Tags: java, jms, jmeter

I am attempting to convert a JMeter test plan I have into a pure Java implementation using the JMeter version 2.12 API but I am having no luck getting the test to execute successfully.  The implementation I have is based off of the test plan .jmx file from the GUI test which does execute successfully when run through the GUI.  The test I am trying to convert is a JMS Publisher sending one text message to an ActiveMQ broker on my localhost. I have confirmed that the message is received when executed through the JMeter GUI but I cannot achieve the same success with the Java implementation. The code compiles and runs, but I'm not sure why the JMS Publisher doesn't successfully send the message:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jmeterLocation = "C:\\Users\\Andrew2\\Desktop\\apache-jmeter-2.12\\";

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    //Load JMeter properties
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterLocation + "bin\\jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterLocation);
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

    //Build Sampler
    PublisherSampler jmsPublisher = new PublisherSampler();
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.jndi_properties", "false");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.initial_context_factory","org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.provider_url","tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.connection_factory","ConnectionFactory");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.topic","dynamicQueues/NewQueue");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.expiration","100");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.priority","6");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.security_principle","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.security_credentials","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.text_message","test..test..");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.input_file","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.random_path","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.config_choice","jms_use_text");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.config_msg_type","jms_text_message");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.iterations","1");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.authenticate",false);
    JMSProperties jmsProperties = new JMSProperties();//set header property
    jmsProperties.addJmsProperty(new JMSProperty("TestID","123456","java.lang.String"));


    //Build Result Collector so that results can be inspected after test
    ResultCollector rc = new ResultCollector();
    rc.setEnabled(true);
    rc.setErrorLogging(false);
    rc.isSampleWanted(true);
    SampleSaveConfiguration ssc = new SampleSaveConfiguration();
    ssc.setTime(false);
    ssc.setLatency(false);
    ssc.setTimestamp(true);
    ssc.setSuccess(true);
    ssc.setLabel(false);
    ssc.setCode(false);
    ssc.setMessage(false);
    ssc.setThreadName(false);
    ssc.setDataType(false);
    ssc.setEncoding(false);
    ssc.setAssertions(false);
    ssc.setSubresults(false);
    ssc.setResponseData(false);
    ssc.setSamplerData(false);
    ssc.setAsXml(false);
    ssc.setFieldNames(false);
    ssc.setResponseHeaders(false);
    ssc.setRequestHeaders(false);
    ssc.setAssertionResultsFailureMessage(false);
    ssc.setThreadCounts(false);
    rc.setSaveConfig(ssc);
    rc.setFilename("C:\\Users\\Andrew2\\Desktop\\constantthroughput-singleserver.csv");

    //Create Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setEnabled(true);
    loopController.setLoops(3);
    loopController.addTestElement(jmsPublisher);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.initialize();

    //Create Thread Group
    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);

    //Create Test Plan
    testPlanTree.add("testPlan",new TestPlan("JMeter JMS test"));
    testPlanTree.add("loopController",loopController);
    testPlanTree.add("JMS Publisher",jmsPublisher);
    testPlanTree.add("Logger",rc);
    testPlanTree.add("ThreadGroup",threadGroup);

    //Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relevant .jmx file you can launch it programatically as per `4.2 Running an existing JMeter Test from Java code` chapter of [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide.

If you looking for a way of designing load test purely in Java, your code is missing some important bits like `TestElement.TEST_CLASS` property. Also ThreadGroup should be represented as HashTree.

See [JMeterFromScratch.java](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/57cef9e2b1c952f669417163b4f0c4a679353719/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java?at=master) source code for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link to JMeterFromScratch.java helped out a lot.  I was able to get the code working just as I needed it to, thanks Dmitri.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example JMeterFromScratch.java Dmitri listed above I have revised my code and now it works, the working code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String jmeterLocation = "C:\\Users\\Andrew2\\Desktop\\apache-jmeter-2.12\\";

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    //Load JMeter properties
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterLocation + "bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterLocation);
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

    //Build Sampler
    PublisherSampler jmsPublisher = new PublisherSampler();
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.jndi_properties", "false");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.initial_context_factory","org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.provider_url","tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.connection_factory","ConnectionFactory");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.topic","dynamicQueues/NewQueue");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.expiration","100");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.priority","6");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.security_principle","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.security_credentials","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.text_message","test..test..");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.input_file","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.random_path","");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.config_choice","jms_use_text");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.config_msg_type","jms_text_message");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.iterations","1");
    jmsPublisher.setProperty("jms.authenticate",false);
    JMSProperties jmsProperties = new JMSProperties();//set header property
    jmsProperties.addJmsProperty(new JMSProperty("TestID","123456","java.lang.String"));


    //Build Result Collector so that results can be inspected after test
    ResultCollector rc = new ResultCollector();
    rc.setEnabled(true);
    rc.setErrorLogging(false);
    rc.isSampleWanted(true);
    SampleSaveConfiguration ssc = new SampleSaveConfiguration();
    ssc.setTime(false);
    ssc.setLatency(false);
    ssc.setTimestamp(true);
    ssc.setSuccess(true);
    ssc.setLabel(false);
    ssc.setCode(false);
    ssc.setMessage(false);
    ssc.setThreadName(false);
    ssc.setDataType(false);
    ssc.setEncoding(false);
    ssc.setAssertions(false);
    ssc.setSubresults(false);
    ssc.setResponseData(false);
    ssc.setSamplerData(false);
    ssc.setAsXml(false);
    ssc.setFieldNames(false);
    ssc.setResponseHeaders(false);
    ssc.setRequestHeaders(false);
    ssc.setAssertionResultsFailureMessage(false);
    ssc.setThreadCounts(false);
    rc.setSaveConfig(ssc);
    rc.setFilename("C:\\Users\\Andrew2\\Desktop\\constantthroughput-singleserver.csv");

    //Create Loop Controller
    LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
    loopController.setEnabled(true);
    loopController.setLoops(1);
    loopController.setFirst(true);
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
    loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
    loopController.initialize();

    //Create Thread Group
    SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
    threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
    threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
    threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
    threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS,ThreadGroup.class.getName());
    threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS,ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

    //Create Test Plan
    TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("New Test Plan");
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
    testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
    testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

    //Load elements into test plan
    testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
    HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(jmsPublisher);
    threadGroupHashTree.add(rc);

    SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterLocation + "bin/testjms.jmx"));

    Summariser summer = null;
    String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
    if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
        summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
    }

    //Run Test Plan
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
}
```